Drag And drop library for Javascript Script
I am relatively new to JavaScript. I wanted to create a project where in I will need to drag and drop to rearrange the order of items. I have no idea how to approach this, I was wondering if there was an library that could help. (I want to do this on JS to learn and understand, for that reason I am not opting for any framework like react or angular)
I haven't tried anything as such for drag and drop. I just have a list of items rendered on the page

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Go and read the Drag and Drop API documentation  over on MDN.

Use SortableJS to easily implement drag-and-drop functionality in vanilla JavaScript for rearranging list items.

I advise you to read the guide to understand how to ask a question correctly and in which cases to do so.
However, I recommend you to use Gridstack js, it is a great JavaScript library to implement drag and drop quickly and easily between containers in your project
